# Can't get Google Maps API to Work

Tags: api, maps

I would like to have a map on the contact page of my sub-domain at http://www.pedregoza.org/birds/contact.html. I have faithfully copied the code in the various examples for google maps, and done the style sheet in my .css. I have specified referral domains such as .pedregoza.org/birds/ etc, all to no avail. I am functional in html and I can edit java scripts when needed, but I find the google maps api to be very complicated, given that the internet is full of similar complaints to mine. Here is the error that I keep on getting: *Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application. The provided key is not a valid Google API Key, or it is not authorized for the Google Maps Javascript API v3 on this site. If you are the owner of this application, you can learn about obtaining a valid key here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key* And yes, I have generated a new key, enabled API v.3, and tried a bunch of other suggestions people have made. If I can't get this to work, then I guess google maps is only useful for static map displays, which is kind of sad. I was hoping people could zoom in and out of the map on our site. If anyone has a suggestion; I would be happy to try it. I know I am not alone with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

First You must get your location Latitude and Longitude from :

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=+" + MapAddress + "&sensor=false
```

try this html code in your page. str_lat and str_lng are your location.

```
    <head>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no' />
    <style type='text/css'>
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map-canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type='text/javascript' src=https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&sensor=false>
    </script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      function initialize() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(str_lat,str_lng);
        var mapOptions = {
          center: myLatlng,
          zoom: 16,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
            mapOptions);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title:'Location!'
        });
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='map-canvas'/>
  </body>
</html>;
```